# Nintendo 3DS face comparison/similarity feature?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-ds

If I recall correctly, on the DS Lite or DSi there was a feature where the camera would take a picture of two separate faces and display a percentage similarity between them - it may also have outputted a possible relationship for the two people, e.g. daughter, mother etc. This was not related to face recognition, it was just an added feature on the console. However, I cannot find mention of this anywhere on the Internet, which leads me to wonder if it was not in fact an inbuilt DS feature but part of an actual game.

**Did this feature ever exist or is my memory incorrect and is there a way to access this feature on the 3DS, or was it not transferred?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The similarity feature *does* indeed exist in the camera app, which is part of the DSi system software.

The feature does not exist on the DS Lite, which does not have a camera in the first place, and does not seem to have carried over to the 3DS. At the very least, I have been unable to find out how to compare faces on the 3DS.